# containsを用いた要素抽出についてです

Tags: python, python3, xml

xmlでdocumentに対して、テキストの数値がarticle-id_pmidであったらpassageの中のparagraphにfirstが含まれていたら抽出するというプログラムを作成しています。

paragraph抽出は、containsを用いたのですがテキストの数値がarticle-id_pmidであるかという箇所が分からなかったので教えて頂きたいです.(xpathを用いてpmidを抽出して、テキストの数値と一致させるとかですかね?)
article-id_pmidとparagraphが違うpassageの中にあるので難しいのかなとも少し思いました

**take.py**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#xmlファイル読み込み
with open('1.xml','r',encoding='utf-8') as xml:      
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

#passageの中のparagraphにfirstが含まれていたら抽出

texts = soup.select('''
passage >
   infon[key="type"]:-soup-contains("paragraph") ~ text:-soup-contains("first") 
''')
text = [t.text for t in texts]
xml.close()

#実行結果を指定のファイルに保存
with open ('take.txt','w')as txt:
  print(text,file=txt)
txt.close
```

**1.txt**

```
1111
2222
```

**1.xml**

```
<collection>
    <document>
    <id>32691</id>
        <passage>
            <infon key="article-id_pmid">1111</infon>
        </passage>
        <passage>
            <infon key="section_type">INTRO</infon>
            <infon key="type">paragraph</infon>
            <text>which was first diagnosed in Wuhan. </text>
        </passage>
    </document>
    <document>
        <id>31435</id>
        <passage>
        <infon key="article-id_pmid">2222</infon>
        </passage>
        <passage>
        <infon key="section_type">INTRO</infon>
        <infon key="type">paragraph</infon>
        <text>>Challenges for Vaccinologists in the first. </text>
        </passage>
    </document>
    <document>
        <id>35643</id>
        <passage>
        <infon key="article-id_pmid">3333</infon>
        </passage>
        <passage>
        <infon key="section_type">INTRO</infon>
        <infon key="type">paragraph</infon>
        <text>>decreased trade, high unemployment. </text>
        </passage>
    </document>
</collection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> テキストの数値がarticle-id_pmidであったら

この「テキストの数値」というのは `1.txt` の中身だとして、CSS セレクタで選別してみます。

なお、`-soup-contains(...)` は引数を `OR` 条件で結合します。

```
[XML element]:-soup-contains("1111", "2222")
=>
("1111" in "XML element text") OR ("2222" in "XML element text")
```

※ `-soup-contains()` はその名前の通りに `contain`(包含)であって exact match ではないので、その点には注意が必要です

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#xmlファイル読み込み
with open('1.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xml:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

#textファイル読み込み
with open('1.txt') as f:
  nums = [n.strip() for n in f.readlines()]

#passageの中のparagraphにfirstが含まれていたら抽出
nums = ','.join(f'"{n}"' for n in nums)
texts = soup.select(f'''
  document:has(> passage > infon[key="article-id_pmid"]:-soup-contains({nums})) >
    passage >
      infon[key="type"]:-soup-contains("paragraph") ~ text:-soup-contains("first")
''')
text = [t.text for t in texts]

#実行結果を指定のファイルに保存
with open('take.txt', 'w') as txt:
  print('\n'.join(text), file=txt)
```